# Getting error: You need to pass a model name to the store's modelFor method

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using Ember 2.6.0

Have the following routes defined:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('brands');
  this.route('brand', {path: '/brands/:brand_id'});
});
```

The model for `brand` is:

```
export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  description: attr('string'),
  dateCreated: attr('date'),
  lastUpdated: attr('date'),
  regions: hasMany('region')
});
```

And the model for `region` is:

```
export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  dateCreated: attr('date'),
  lastUpdated: attr('date'),
  brand: belongsTo('brand')
});
```

Now, when trying to access `/brands` I am doing this in the route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('brand');
  }
});
```

I am getting the following error:

> You need to pass a model name to the store's modelFor method

This worked prior to adding the `brand` route and `region` relationships. Brand is the parent, so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

UPDATE:

Removing `regions: hasMany('region')` from the `brand` model allows things to work again. Not sure why it isn't working with the defined relationship.

Comment: Do you use pods? What is the full path of your region model?

Comment: I've tried both with and without pods. currently, I'm not using pods. So full path is `<project-folder>/app/models/region.js`. Brand is right next to it in the same folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it turns out I had to create serializers for each object. For brand I have:

```
import RESTSerializer from 'ember-data/serializers/rest';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
      regions: {embedded: 'always'}
  }
});
```

And for `region` I have:

```
import RESTSerializer from 'ember-data/serializers/rest';

export default RESTSerializer.extend({
});
```

Technically, it works without the region serializer but I get a warning that ember couldn't find `regions` inside the `region` model. I may submit a ticket to ember to suggest not having to create an empty `RESTSerializer` just to avoid this warning.

Comment: If you are embedding the regions, your relationship should be `regions: hasMany('region', { async: false })`, because when embedding, your relationship is not async (when omitting this, ember data will default to async true)

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't really have anything to do with this Q&A because since the data is already there, Ember is smart enough to ignore the async: true bit.

Comment: Which version of ember-data you're using? This error sounds like it's mixing old and new serializer implementations (with and without conversion to JSON API). Which seems strange to me if you're using any up to date ember-data version.

Comment: ember-data version 2.6.1

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was coming across a very similar issue in my app, as well and this solved it for me.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! One recommendation: since this solution relates to interpreting payload response with EmbeddedRecordsMixin, for brevity you may not need to list the serializer/router code as that seems to be more anecdotal to the application serializer you're using.