# Error while trying to load ember data model from REST API

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Version: Ember 2.11

I am trying to use Ember data model to load the data from REST API but it is failing with error message as 
"**ember.debug.js:17634 TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at Class._pushInternalModel (store.js:2005)**

Here is more details:
1. REST API response is:

```
     {  
      "sfresults":[  
              {  
               "url":"https://google.com/1",
               "title":"Titl1",
               "description":"Description1",
              "type":"KB",
              "lastModifiedDate":"12/23/16",
              "viewScore":"86.12006476690622",
              "caseNumber":"case1",
              "id":"cd4ac3e8-c3ac-4be5-ad11-c62a85ddf289"
             },
            {  
               "url":"https://google.com/2",
               "title":"Titl2",
               "description":"Description2",
               "type":"KB",
               "lastModifiedDate":"12/23/16",
                "viewScore":"86.12006476690622",
               "caseNumber":"case2",
              "id":"cd4ac3e8-c3ac-4be5-ad11-c62a85ddf289"
           },
        ],
    "message":"SUCCESS",
   "id":"3bd116c7-db63-4277-8ace-a7ea846a04ee"
  }
```

**Controller code:**

```
          let sfdata = this.store.query('sfresult',{ 'searchText': inputSearchText, 'searchType' : 'SF' } );
           this.set('sfresult', sfdata);
```

**My Models**

```
 sfresult.js

      import DS from 'ember-data';
      export default  DS.Model.extend({
      sfresults: DS.hasMany('sfresults'),
      message: DS.attr('string')
     });

sfresults.js
       import DS from 'ember-data';

       export default  DS.Model.extend({

       title: DS.attr('string'),
       description: DS.attr('string'),
       caseNumber: DS.attr('string'),
       lastModifiedDate: DS.attr('string'),
       type: DS.attr('string'),
       url: DS.attr('string'),
       searchText: DS.attr('string'),
       messageId: DS.attr('string')
     });

     export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
     host: 'http://localhost:8080',
    namespace: 'server'
   });
```

Then i wanted to iterate sfresult and show it in the UI. but here as soon as API call response comes back it is unable to load into ember data models. fails with above error.

Note: if i try without hasMany model it works fine - meaning json response having array of elements and using only sfresults model without sfresult, but wanted to get the message in the JSON response to act accordingly - please ignore this statement if it is confusing a bit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What serializer are you using?

Comment: using RESTAdapter. it works fine for simple JSON responses but i wanted to have hasMany

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure you are using the RESTSerializer. By default the serializer in a new app is JSONAPISerializer, which throws the error that you are seeing.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions - i made the changes as you recommended but seeing different error. for now I am marking your answer as correct one. I have posted a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927705/getting-error-you-need-to-pass-a-model-name-to-the-stores-modelfor-method , please see if you can answer that. thanks again for your help.